# mod_rewrite http_host

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How can I prevent access to a subdirectory based on HTTP_HOST.

I have 2 parked domains pointing to one directory. They both serve up the same website.

However I wish each to have a seperate wordpress blog. To do this I'm installing them in different directories.

domain1.com/domain1-blog/
domain2.com/domain2-blog/

The trouble is the directories are accessible across domains. For instance

domain1.com/domain2-blog/
domain2.com/domain1-blog/

I REALLY don't want people to be able to access across domains.  Wordpress will break and I will get duplicate content issues in Google.

What is the EXACT code I need to put into my htaccess file to serve up a 404 error should anyone try to access

domain1.com/domain2-blog/
OR
domain2.com/domain1-blog/

I thought maybe using HTTP_HOST combined with mod_rewrite somehow?

I'm a big newb when it comes to htaccess, so the more explicit you can be the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if its domain1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
#and the request is for domain2 blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain2-blog/ [NC]
#send a 403 forbidden
RewriteRule . - [F,L]

#if its domain2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com$ [NC]
#and the request is for domain1 blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain1-blog/ [NC]
#send a 403 forbidden
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks a lot! The comments are very useful too.

Comment: I'm curious, would there be a way to also rewrite the URL so that to the visitor it would look like they where at domain1.com/blog/ or domain2.com/blog/ even though they actually be calling files from domain1.com/domain1-blog/ and domain2.com/domain2-blog/